# Get Only Unread Messages from QuickBlox?

Tags: ios, chat, message, quickblox

I had integrated `QuickBlox` SDK in my chat application.

I am Bit frustrated with an issue of unread messages or say offline messages.

In offline messages `QuickBlox` do send the push notification. But some where it gets skipped to store at app side.

Like say if i got notification of 25 messages and i click on one of message from notification and app gets open but how can i get those 24 unread(Offline) messages.

There are few methods given by `QuickBlox` to retrieve messages.

1. For Group

   ```
   [[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithJID:room.JID  membersOnly:YES persistent:YES historyAttribute:@{@"maxstanzas": count}]; // Where count is the unread messages count which i get from the `QBChatDialog`, And this code gives me unread messages from the `XMPP` server.
   ```
2. Private and Group both from `QuickBlox`

   ```
    NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   extendedRequest[@"limit"] = @(limit);
   if (offset) {
       extendedRequest[@"skip"] = @([offset integerValue]);
   }
   extendedRequest[@"sort_desc"] = @"date_sent";
   [QBChat messagesWithDialogID:dialogID extendedRequest:extendedRequest delegate:self];
   ```

Both of above method return me the messages from last. But some of messages in between gets skipped. So how can i get those perticular messages.

By short and simple i just want the messages that are unread without passing its count as count gives the messages that are from last.

So is there any method that `QuickBlox` have to retrieve only unread message.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can save a datetime where your application has been closed( or moved to background ). Then when you receive push, you can load dialogs from previously saved datetime.